# Chi empty http.Request.Body in render.Bind

Tags: json, http, go, go-chi

I am using [github.com/pressly/chi](http://github.com/pressly/chi) to build this simple program where I try to decode some JSON from the `http.Request.Body`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/pressly/chi"
    "github.com/pressly/chi/render"
)

type Test struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func (p *Test) Bind(r *http.Request) error {
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(p)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Post("/products", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var p Test
        // err := render.Bind(r, &p)
        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&p)

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(p)
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}
```

When I don't use `render.Bind()` (from `"github.com/pressly/chi/render"`), it works as expected.

However, when I uncomment the line `err := render.Bind(r, &p)` and I comment the line `err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&p)`, it panics with `EOF` :

> `2017/06/20 22:26:39 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:39696: EOF`

and thus the `json.Decode()` fails.

Am I doing something wrong or is the `http.Request.Body` is already read somewhere else before `render.Bind()` is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[render.Bind](https://github.com/pressly/chi/blob/master/render/render.go#L20)'s purpose is to perform decode and execute `Bind(r)` to do post decode operations.

For eg.:

```
type Test struct {
   Name string `json:"name"`
}

func (p *Test) Bind(r *http.Request) error {
   // At this point, Decode is already done by `chi`
   p.Name = p.Name + " after decode"
  return nil
}
```

If you have to do only JSON decode no other actions needs to be done after decode with respect to decoded values. Just use:

```
// Use Directly JSON decoder of std pkg
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&p)
```

OR

```
// Use wrapper method from chi DecodeJSON
err := render.DecodeJSON(r.Body, &p)
```

Comment: Indeed, I should have check the source code of `render.Bind`... that explains why the `Body` was empty, since it had already be read. Anyway, thanks for the solution !